# Disable Smarty on a single page in ActiveCollab

Tags: php, jqgrid, smarty, activecollab

I'm working on a system (ActiveCollab) that uses Smarty for templates. I want to output some JSON so I need to have it output by itself... no other cruft. However, if I do NOT provide a Smarty template file for the corresponding action I get an error output that ruins the JSON.

Does anyone know how to disable Smarty output on a case by case basis? In pseudocode, something like

```
$this->smarty->disable();
```

Failing that, does anyone know how to have ActiveCollab not require a template file for output? Or even know of a better way to output JSON for consumption within ActiveCollab?

My main goal is to output json for use by jqgrid within ActiveCollab, in case that helps.

Thanks.

---

EDIT:

It turns out it's as simple as adding `die();` after the desired output.

```
function bar(){
    echo $myoutput;
    die();
}
```

That's it. Why I always look for the "hard" answer when the solution is so basic I will never know... *sigh*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

activeCollab will automatically render page layout around page content only if action itself did not provide an exit before it ended execution. This exit may be:

1. Serving some data with `$this->serveData()`
2. Page redirection
3. Simple printing of content + die()
4. File forward, using `download_file()` and `download_content()` function
5. Any other exist that stops execution of action (dies within it)

In your case, you can use controller's `serveData()` method to serve JSON:

```
function action() {
  $my_json_data = array('something');

  $this->serveData($my_json_data, null, FORMAT_JSON);
}
```

This function will set proper HTTP headers and encode the value that you are sending.

Comment: The serveData method is just what I was looking for. Thx!